# LINQ how to see rows in a row

Tags: asp.net, database, linq

I have this table:

```
id   owner   model  
1    1       circle  
2    1       rectangle  
3    1       squire 
4    1       pyramid
5    2       apple  
6    2       orange   
8    3       circle  
9    3       rectangle  
10   3       star
```

and I need to output:

```
owner   model 1    model 2       model 3     model 4
1       circle     rectangle     squire      pyramid
2       apple      orange          
3       circle     rectangle     star
```

please help.

Comment: Have you made any attempt at this?  It seems like a fairly straightforward loop structure should be able to make this happen.  For each distinct owner value, select the model values.  Then either add those to a data structure of some kind or output them to the view directly.

Comment: i don't know LINQ. i checked in this in SQL select statement, but i couldn't success, i want to know LINQ can do it.

Comment: LINQ can be used in the logic for this, sure.  But if you don't know LINQ then perhaps you would otherwise use something else?  Whatever you use to fetch the data from the database surely returns some sort of enumerable set of records/objects.  The same logic would work on that.

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL select to see rows in columns](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19194492/sql-select-to-see-rows-in-columns)